# Flutter build issue: Dart snapshot generator failed with exit code -9

Tags: android, flutter

I get following exception when building flutter apk or appbundle. It happens randomly. I don't know what triggers it. How can I debug this further?

```
Dart snapshot generator failed with exit code -9                        
                                                                        
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* Where:                                                                
Script '/var/theproject/libs/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1035
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.            
> Process 'command '/var/theproject/libs/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
                                                                        
* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                        
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              
                                                                        
BUILD FAILED in 6m 51s                                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     412.5s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Here is my flutter doctor -v result:

```
Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 2.2.2 at /var/theproject/libs/flutter
    • Framework revision d79295af24 (6 days ago), 2021-06-11 08:56:01
      -0700
    • Engine revision 91c9fc8fe0
    • Dart version 2.13.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /var/theproject/libs/android-sdk-linux
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: /usr/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_282-b08)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at
    google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome
      executable.

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from
      https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit
      https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for
      detailed instructions).

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, what it solved was to use variables from other class with static and not by creating a instance:

Works fine:

```js
import file
ClassName.variable
```

Bug:

```js
import file
var instance = ClassName()
instance.variable
```